# Unable to create sign up page by extending ArrayAdapter with ListView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Here is the code for extended ArrayAdapter class:

```
public class MultiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity a1;
private final String[] s1;


public MultiAdapter(Activity a, String[] s){
    super(a,R.layout.loginlist,s);
    s1=s;
    a1=a;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int i,View v,ViewGroup vg) {
    LayoutInflater li = a1.getLayoutInflater();
    View v1 = li.inflate(R.layout.loginlist, null, true);

    TextView tv;
    tv = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(s1[i]);
    EditText et;
    et = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    if (tv.getText().equals("Name")||tv.getText().equals("User Name")||tv.getText().equals("Company")) {
        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
    if (tv.getText().equals("Phone")) {
        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    }
    if (tv.getText().equals("E-mail")||tv.getText().equals("Company E-mail")) {
        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    }
    if (tv.getText().equals("Password")||tv.getText().equals("Re-type Password")) {
        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    }


    return v1;
    }



}
```

loginlist.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10" >

</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

What's happening is that whenever I click on the "Name", "Company" or "User Name" edittext's the cursor automatically jumps to the password and then re-type password edittext field. This does not happen on any other fields. What's causing this?

Comment: Why your completing simple login with adapter and list view. You can achieve it using simple linearlayout

Comment: Because it is easier.

Comment: U can use simple linear layout and work on it. As I can see your not using proper adapter concept. First you need check for convert view for null if null then go for population of view by layout inflator else go view holder stub concept.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you said?

Answer (score 0):

> @Override  public View getView(int position, View convertView,
>   ViewGroup parent) {  View row;  if (null == convertView) {
>
> row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);  } else
>
> {  row = convertView;  }  TextView tv =
>   (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1); 
>   tv.setText(items[position]);  tv.setTypeface(font);
>
> return row; }

This how you have to implement your `getview`.  Check on null check on convert view. But I would strongly recommend you use linear layout.

Comment: I implemented what you said. It's still not working. logcat: 05-16 11:12:21.700: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25175): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-16 11:12:40.540: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25175): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection